# Parse html5 parent elements in dojo parser under Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, widget, html5shiv

I am getting an error when trying to use dojo widget templates with html5 elements as parent elements under Internet Explorer 8. This doesn't happen under Firefox or Chrome, nor under newer versions of Internet Explorer.

This is a standard dojo widget included declaratively on a page, e.g. like this:

```
<div data-dojo-type="some/path/to/master/Footer"></div>
```

The Footer.js is simply:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
    "dojo/text!./templates/footer.html",
    "dojo/i18n!./nls/footer"
], function(declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, template, i18n){
    return declare("some.path.to.Footer", [ _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {
        templateString: template,
        i18n: i18n
    });
});
```

The error that I am seeing in Internet Explorer 8 console:

```
Error: Invalid template: <footer class="footer-wrapper gradient3">(...)
```

I also don't see this error if I wrap the `footer` element in another div so that footer isn't the parent element, e.g. like this:

```
<div>
<footer class="footer-wrapper gradient3">
```

I couldn't find any mentions of this issue, has anyone heard of problems like this one before?

Comment: Not really, probably adding the parent div is an acceptable workaround.